# Computing the distance between a point and a line without cross product

Tags: geometry, matlab, 3d

Let P be an arbitrary point. Let S be a segment.

Is there any way of computing the shortest distance between P and S without using cross product?

I found a [formula that uses cross product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html). However, I need to calculate the distance for millions of points. (~ 100 million points)

I am using MATLAB, and using the profiler I realized that the cross product function is taking most of the computation time.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let the line segment be $x(t) = x_0 + t d_0$ with $t \in [0,1]$.

You want to solve $\min_{t \in [0,1]} \|x(t) -p_0\|$.

Let $\phi(t) = \|x(t) -p_0\|^2 = ||x_0-p_0\|^2+t^2 \|d_0\|^2-2 t \langle p_0 -x_0, d_0 \rangle$. $\phi$ is a convex quadratic, hence it has a unique minimum, and distance increases as $t$ moves away from the minimizing $t$. Hence we can solve the unconstrained problem first, and then 'project' the solution $t'$ back onto $[0,1]$.

The unconstrained solution is found by solving $\phi'(t') = 0$, which gives
$t' = \frac{\langle p_0 -x_0, d_0 \rangle}{\|d_0\|^2}$. Now let $t_0 = \min(1, \max(0, t'))$. Then the shortest distance is given by $\|x(t_0) - p_0\|$.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to check the distance to the *segment* and not to the line, you will have to check that it is not "beyond" one of the endpoints.  That is, that the orthogonal projection of the point $x_0$ is between $x_1$ and $x_2$.  If not, the answer will be the distance to the closest of the two endpoints.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
input vectors x0,x1,x2

// if x0,x1,x2 form an obtuse angle, then x0 is closest to x1
if dotprod(x0-x1,x2-x1) < 0 then
    return dist(x0,x1)

// if x0,x2,x1 form an obtuse angle, then x0 is closest to x2
else if dotprod(x0-x2,x1-x2) < 0 then
    return dist(x0,x2)

else 
    return abs(crossprod(x0-x1,x2-x1))/dist(x2,x1)
```

Cross products and dot products should be relatively inexpensive in terms of compute cost, as they are only a handful of floating point operations each.  I know nothing about matlab, but you might want to check if another language would yield performance increases.